# Firebase Initialization failure in jest test

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs, slack-api, firebase-admin

I'm writing some tests for event handlers for a [slack bolt](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts) app. Yesterday I wrote a whole suite of tests for all my event handlers which all passed perfectly and life was wonderful. Then, I did some refactoring, and now my whole suite fails to even run, and instead I just see error saying that firebase failed to initialise.

Firebase fails to initialise because jest doesn't have the environment variables it would need, in order to initialise firebase correctly. But, I don't want it to initialise of course. And yesterday, it wasn't. So I'm trying to work out why it is trying to initialise firebase when running tests now, when it didn't seem to be, before.

The simplest test I have, in `Events.test.ts` just tests the `handleBlockActions` function in `Events.ts`, which just acknowledges a slack event. This test works absolutely fine, until there is a function `Event.ts` which makes a database call. Even thought I'm not importing `handleTeamRename` into `Events.test.ts`, if I have that function in `Events.ts`, the test fails with the firebase message as below. If I comment out the line which calls `updateOrganizationName`, then the test passes.

I don't understand why just *having* a function which calls the db in a file I import *something else* from, is enough to make my test fail due to firebase failing to initialise properly.

I've trying to produce a minimal example; the original files have more functions in them, but I've made copies and removed everything I can to reproduce the problem with the smallest mount of code.

I'd be really grateful if someone can help me understand what jest is doing, why it's trying to initialise firebase despite, as far as I can tell, me not asking it to, and how I can better handle this situation.

Most of the other answers I can find are about mocking firebase more generally and I want to avoid that if I can at the moment - which given that it seemed to work yesterday, seems possible?

file structure

```
- database
    - Organizations.ts
    - Slack.ts
    - firebase.ts
- services
    - Events.test.ts
    - Events.ts
```

```ts
// Events.ts

import { AckFn, DialogValidation, SayArguments } from "@slack/bolt";
import { updateOrganizationName } from "../database/Organizations";
import { getSlackTeam } from "../database/Slack";

export type AckFnSig =
  | AckFn<void>
  | AckFn<string | SayArguments>
  | AckFn<DialogValidation>;

/**
 * A user renames the organization name in slack
 */
export const handleTeamRename = async (
  userId: string,
  token: string
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const team = await getSlackTeam(token, userId);
    // if I comment out this line, the test passes
    await updateOrganizationName(team.id, team.name, team.icon.image_230);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("team_rename event");
    console.error(e);
  }
};

/**
 * Acknowledge user clicking on action button
 */
export const handleBlockActions = async (ack: AckFnSig): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    ack();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("action_link_accounts event");
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

```
// Events.test.ts

import { AckFnSig, handleBlockActions } from "./Events";

describe("events", () => {
  describe("handleBlockActions", () => {
    it("should ack block actions", async () => {
      const mockAck = jest.fn();

      void (await handleBlockActions(
        (mockAck as unknown) as AckFnSig
      ));

      await expect(mockAck).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

```
 FAIL  src/services/Events.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.

       8 | admin.initializeApp({
       9 |   // current required type appears to be wrong so has to be cast as any
    > 10 |   credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseServiceKey as any),
         |                                ^
      11 |   databaseURL:
      12 |     process.env.FIREBASE_URL || "[my firebase url]",
      13 | });

      at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
      at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
      at new FirebaseAppError (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:125:28)
      at new ServiceAccount (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:134:19)
      at new ServiceAccountCredential (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:68:15)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.cert (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential.js:34:54)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/database/firebase.ts:10:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was working yesterday because the event handlers used to be in a file which imported `app` from `index.ts`. This file loaded the `env`, and therefore jest was able to initialize firebase - even though I didn't think it was - so it didn't complain about any database functions.

So, to fix this I am going to look at handling my env vars in jest better, and then look at mocking out firebase properly.